# Evaluating the sum $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{F_n}{2015^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

> Find $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{F_n}{2015^n}$$
>
> Where $F_n$ is the $n$-th Fibonacci number.

Any clues?

Comment: I think I've seen $F_1=1$, $F_2=1$, $F_3=2$, $F_4=3$, $F_5=5$, $F_6=8$, etc, starting with $1$ rather than with $0$.  By the usual recurrence then, $F_0$ would have to be $0$.  So why start with $0$ rather than with $1$? $\qquad$

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo! And this is the question as is in my homework, but sure, we could start from 1 as well.

Comment: @Michael: I should hope that you’ve seen it: $F_0=0,F_1=1$ is the standard indexing.

Comment: Finding $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 {F_n}$ is more interesting. $\qquad$

Comment: @Michael: Could you explain how to find that?

Comment: @Astronomy: that is the [reciprocal Fibonacci constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_Fibonacci_constant), a trascendental number related with some Jacobi theta functions. A series with an interesting closed form is, instead, $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{F_n F_{n+1}}.$$ Continued fractions are deeply involved.

Comment: @Astronomy : I could.  But it should be a separate question.  It's easy to show that series converges (since its tail is bounded by a convergent geometric sequence with positive terms) but finding the exact value of the sum takes more work than that. $\qquad$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint:** If we write the generating function
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty F_n x^n
$$
then because $F_{n+2} = F_{n+1} + F_n$,
$$
f(x) = x + (x + x^2) f(x).
$$
Therefore,
$$
f(x) = \frac{x}{1 - x - x^2}.
$$
Your sum is $f\left(\frac{1}{2015}\right)$.

Comment: Whenever I answer a question that doesn't mention generating functions with a generating function solution, there's always that one downvoter. I can't tell if they don't know what a generating function is, or if they just don't like them for pedagogical reasons.

Comment: +1. It's straightforward that generating function is the solution. Recently, I received comments like "I don't like colors", "I don't like the solutions which are enclosed in a box", "you have to many spaces", "you arrive to a miracle",  "you are flooding MSE with digammas", etc... Don't worry, be happy is an old song. Your answer is pretty fine.

Comment: @FelixMarin: I fully agree! (+1)

Answer (score 3):

Use [Binet's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Binet.27s_formula), $$F_n=\frac 1{\sqrt 5}\left(\left(\frac {1+\sqrt 5}2\right)^n-\left(\frac {1-\sqrt 5}2\right)^n\right)$$  Plug that into your sum and you have two geometric series to sum.

Answer (score 2):

There are two geometric series in disguise, since 
$$F_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\alpha^n-\beta^n\right),\tag{1}$$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the real roots of the second degree polynomial $x^2-x-1$. Such closed formula is straightforward to prove by induction on $n$, since both sides of $(1)$ equal $0$ at $n=0$, equal $1$ at $n=1$ and fulfill the recurrence $R_{n+2}=R_{n+1}+R_n$. The same argument leads to the identity:
$$ \forall x:|x|<\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2},\qquad \sum_{n\geq 0}F_n x^n = \frac{x}{1-x-x^2},\tag{2} $$
and by evaluating $(2)$ at $x=\frac{1}{2015}$,
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{F_n}{2015^n} = \color{red}{\frac{2015}{4058209}}\tag{3}$$
readily follows.

Answer (score 0):

One heavy-handed way of approaching this is to start by proving that
$$
F_n = \frac 1 {\sqrt 5} \left( \left( \frac{1 + \sqrt 5} 2 \right)^n - \left( \frac{1 - \sqrt 5} 2 \right)^n \right).
$$
That can be done by induction on $n$, using the recurrence satisfied by the Fibonacci numbers.

After that, you just need to sum two separate geometric series and add them.